# Creating a PersistentVolume on Okteto Cloud

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, okteto

When I try to create a persistentVolume on Okteto Cloud with the following definition:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=persistentvolumes", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=PersistentVolume"
Name: "postgres-pv", Namespace: ""
Object: &{map["apiVersion":"v1" "kind":"PersistentVolume" "metadata":map["annotations":map["kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":""] "labels":map["app":"postgres" "type":"local"] "name":"postgres-pv"] "spec":map["accessModes":["ReadWriteMany"] "capacity":map["storage":"5Gi"] "hostPath":map["path":"/mnt/data"]]]}
from server for: "deploy/k8s.postgres.yml": persistentvolumes "postgres-pv" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:okteto:07e6fdbf-55c2-4642-81e3-051e8309000f" cannot get resource "persistentvolumes" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

However according to [the Okteto cloud docs](https://okteto.com/docs/cloud/multitenancy.html), persistentVolumes seem to be authorized.

**How would I create one on there ?**

.

For context I'm trying to reproduce a simple postgres deployment (no replication, no backups).
Here's my complete deployment file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP  
  ports:
  - name: postgres
    port: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: postgresadmin
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin123

---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Persistent volumes is a cluster-wide resource and it is not allowed.
The docs are wrong, thanks for pointing it out.

You can create instead PersistentVolumeClaims using the default storage class (and remove the persistent volume manifest):

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: postgres-pv-claim
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 10Gi
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: That worked great, thanks ! I suppose you meant "not allowed" though ?